# Does detox tests have access to code in my react-native app?

Tags: react-native, detox

So inside my firstTest.e2e.js file I have stuff like:

```
describe('All tests', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    //can add code here to do something before each it test
  });

  it('Take screenshot', async () => {
    await device.takeScreenshot('home');
  });
});
```

My question is if from this file do I have access to any of code in my actual app or is it working outside of my app? Can I call a helper class inside my app/src folder?